# Load the trained bert model in pth format into the SentenceTransformer

Tags: python, bert-language-model

I want to evaluate my classification model, which is a pth format, trained with bert, using MTEB test, but in MTEB, I want to load it as a sentenceTransformer, so I try to load bert as a sentenceTransformer, but I get an error. what should I do ?
Note : https://paperswithcode.com/paper/mteb-massive-text-embedding-benchmark
Note : https://github.com/embeddings-benchmark/mteb

Comment: The code didn't go up, so I linked to the notion.
https://www.notion.so/q-7e6f925126ab420da142a8cb2e81bef7?pvs=4